# Submit Form data from ajax response

Tags: ajax, form-submit

is it possible to submit a Form from ajax response data ?

```
$.ajax(
{
    url : formURL,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data : postData,
    success:function(response) 
    {
        response.form_data.submit();
        //submit "response.form_data" will be <form>...</form>
    }
});
```

Didn't though that this will work...
Worked like a charm!